# postfix/policyd-weight[11026]: warning: child: could not open RBL Lookup Socket to config

Tags: postfix

i have some problems with my postfix server.
Here the error message from my `mail.warn`:

```
Dec 24 14:43:36 serv postfix/policyd-weight[23064]: warning: child: could not open RBL Lookup Socket to config: IO::Socket::INET: Bad hostname 'config' Invalid argument
Dec 24 14:43:36 serv postfix/policyd-weight[23064]: warning: child: err: can't resolve "config" to address at /usr/lib/perl5/Net/DNS/Resolver/Base.pm line 755, <GEN527> line 26.#012
```

here is my `main.cf`:

```
myhostname                   = serv.wmyc.eu
mydomain                     = serv.wmyc.eu.local
myorigin                     = $myhostname
```

and here is the output of my `hostname -f`:

```
wmyc.eu
```

Comment: as additional check, please edit the question to add the contents of /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/policyd-weight.conf

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not related to Postfix, it's related to the policyd-weight configuration.

policyd-weight uses reasonable defaults. However, if you ever decided to give policyd-weight a configuration file, this might cause a problem after an update and changed configs.

I'd recommend having a look in `/usr/local/etc` for a `policyd-weight.conf` or in `/etc` or `/etc/default` if you're running a Debian/Ubuntu system.

Alternatively, please post the relevant lines of your `main.cf` and `master.cf` (`grep policy /etc/postfix/*`)